Delta Method and the Variance Convergence
In the references I've seen, the $\Delta$-method is typically formulated in terms of convergence in distribution: for $X_i$ i.i.d., $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mu$ and $\mathrm{Var}_\mu(X_i)=\sigma^2<\infty$ (so a CLT holds for the sample mean, $\bar{X}_n$), and $g$ a sufficiently smooth function,
$$
\sqrt{n}g(\bar{X}_n) -g(\mu))\Rightarrow N(0,g'(\mu)^2\sigma^2)
$$
I'm looking at a paper (see (11) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06222) that has the following estimate:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} n \mathbb{E}[(\bar{X}_n) -g(\mu))^2] = g'(\mu)^2\sigma^2
$$
I realized, I wasn't sure how to map the CLT type weak convergence into this convergence of the second central moment.  How would I argue for that?
EDIT: Unsurprisingly, I have found that if we have prior bounds on the derivatives, then the result holds (see the textbook by Bickel and Doksum).  But that assumption does not seem to be present in the Song & Ermon paper.

I don't know what conditions are imposed in the paper you reference, but uniform integrability of $\{n(g(\bar{X}_n)-g(\mu))^2\}$ gives the result. Specifically, the following result holds under uniform integrability.

Suppose $Y_n\xrightarrow{d} Y$ and that $\{Y_n^r\}$ is uniformly integrable for some $r\geq 1$. Then $\mathbb{E}[\vert Y \vert^r_n]\to \mathbb{E}[\vert Y \vert^r]$ as $n\to \infty$.

Proving this is a bit tricky. A well known result is that $Y_n\xrightarrow{d} Y$ if and only if for any bounded and continuous function $g$, $\mathbb{E}[g(Y_n)]\to \mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$. However, our function of interest, $f(x)=\vert x\vert^r$, is unbounded. Naturally, we will use a truncation argument. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ arbitary.
First, let $g_n(x)=|x|^r\land n$, which is bounded and is continuous as the composition of continuous functions. Then, by monotone convergence and since $g$ is bounded and continuous, we have $$\mathbb{E}[|Y|^r] \xleftarrow{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|Y|^r\land n] \xleftarrow{k\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|Y_k|^r\land n]$$ Since $\sup_k \mathbb{E}[|Y_k|]<\infty$ by uniform integrability,  $$\mathbb{E}[|Y|^r]=\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{k\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|Y_k|^r\land n]\leq \sup_k \mathbb{E}[|Y_k|]<\infty$$
Therefore, $X\in L^r$ so $\{X^r\}$ is a UI class as a singleton set of an $L^1$ r.v..
Next, define $h$ as $h(x)=\max (-K,\min(x,K))$, this is continuous as the composition of continuous functions is continuous and is bounded by some $K>0$. Further, $|x-h(x)|\leq \vert x\vert \mathbb{I}\{|x|>K\}$ . So, we can derive that \begin{align*}
    |\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r]-\mathbb{E}[|Y^r]| &\leq |\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r]-\mathbb{E}[h(|Y_n|^r)]| \\
    &+|\mathbb{E}[h(|Y_n|^r)]-\mathbb{E}[h(|Y|^r)]| \\
    &+|\mathbb{E}[h(|Y|^r)]-\mathbb{E}[|Y|^r]| \\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}[||Y_n|^r-h(|Y_n|^r)|] \\
    &+ |\mathbb{E}[h(|Y_n|^r)]-\mathbb{E}[h(|Y|^r)]| \\
    &+\mathbb{E}[||Y|^r-h(|Y|^r)|] \\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r;|Y_n|^r>K] \\
    &+ |\mathbb{E}[h(|Y_n|^r)]-\mathbb{E}[h(|Y|^r)]| \\
    &+\mathbb{E}[|Y|^r;|Y|^r>K]
\end{align*}
So we can get our bound as follows. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. First, pick $K_0$ large enough so that by uniform integrability of $\{|Y_n|^r\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $\{|Y|^r\}$, $\sup_n\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r;|Y_n|^r>K_0]<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ and $\mathbb{E}[|Y|^r;|Y|^r>K_0]<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. Then, given this $K_0$, since $h$ is bounded and continuous, there exists some $n_0$ for which $$n>n_0 \implies |\mathbb{E}[h(|Y_n|^r)]-\mathbb{E}[h(|Y|^r)]|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
So, using this $K_0$ we see $$n>n_0 \implies  |\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r-|Y|^r]|<\varepsilon$$
Meaning $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r]\to \mathbb{E}[|Y|^r]$ as $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary.
Taking $r=2$ and $Y_n=\sqrt{n}(g(\bar{X}_n)-g(\mu))$ gives you your result from the $\Delta$-method convergence in distribution.

In your context, my $X_n$ correspond to the sample means on $n$ i.i.d. samples.  Assuming finiteness of sufficient moments (such that a CLT will hold), is that enough to get the uniform integrability that is essential to your argument?
